# Hibernate map a class as another one

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, orm

I am trying to map a class which looks like:

```
public class Skills {
    private int[] levels; // 10 elements
}
```

Now, mapping an array in Hibernate is a big pain and as I had no luck at all doing that before, I am trying a different approach. Each and every of the 10 elements, actually represents a skill itself. Think of it as ATK, STR, DEX, INT, et cetera. Due to a few design restrictions, it has to be used as an array, otherwise I'd simply add 10 fields to it, of course.

The real pain is in mapping that in SQL to make more sense. Sure, Hibernate can do Serialization of the class but that drills bytes into columns. Now I wonder, is there any way to specify something like CompoundUserType (me being able to say "hey, this is how the table will look, and this is each value of the field!"), or indicate that I in some way want to provide a Skills$Hbm subclass which contains something along

```
class Hbm {
    private int atk, str, dex, Int... ;
}
```

to let me get a nicer table? I'm pretty clueless on what a viable approach can be.

Comment: may I know, why you are are creating a array of levels in the skills table. Instead you normalize it by creating a new levels table where you can store information about different levels of skills and store a reference of the level in the skills table:         
(i.e.    public class skills { private Level level; }
)

Comment: So, the field has to be an array? Can't you declare it as `List`, and add getter and setter that work with array?

Answer (score 0):

may I know, why you are are creating a array of levels in the skills table. Instead you normalize it by creating a new levels table where you can store information about different levels of skills and store a reference of the level in the skills table: i.e.              `public class skills { private Level level; }`

You can also use the `List<Integer> Levels;` instead of using array.

Comment: As I said in the post, it's a design limitation in the structure of the application. It would get utterly messy if I had to turn it all around (I have previously considered your approach, really) so I need to go with a different one.